# Division, match elements and update in XSLT multiple templates

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Tricky and bit confusing problem statement:
1.get the *price* divided *quantity* value for the *desktop* and update it to the *price* of elements where *ordernumber* matches value of *phoneid* and *price*>0 
2.Also update only to elements where *name* is  *desktop2* or *desktop3*. only one at a time
Note: *Desktop* can be multiple, but with a different phone id, so is the  *desktop2*, *desktop3*

Need it in separate templates, since i already have rules to select only few fields for *desktop2* and *desktop3* where i am using custom tags and copying the value, for example *price* to *netprice* as shown in output xml.

Input

```
   <listoforders>
     <Orderitem>
    <name>Desktop</name>
    <place>NZ</place>
    <netprice>120</netprice>
   <quantity>2</quantity>
   <itemproperties>
   <name>phoneid</name>
   <value>1234</value>
   </itemproperties>
   </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop2</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <netprice>140</price>
        <ordernumber>1234</ordernumber>
    </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop2</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <netprice>0</price>
       <ordernumber>1234</ordernumber>           
       <objectid>1</objectid>

    </Orderitem>
     <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop2</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <netprice>0</price>
    <ordernumber>1234</ordernumber>        
    </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop2</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
    <ordernumber>12345</ordernumber>            
    <netprice>130</price>
    </Orderitem>
           <Orderitem>
    <name>Desktop</name>
    <place>NZ</place>
    <price>120</price>
    <quantity>3</quantity>
    <associationid>2</associationid>
    <itemproperties>
        <name>phoneid</name>
        <value>12345</value>
    </itemproperties>
   </Orderitem>
   <Orderitem>
    <name>Desktop2</name>
    <place>NZ</place>
    <price>0</price>
    <ordernumber>12345</ordernumber>
   </Orderitem>
   <Orderitem>
    <name>Desktop2</name>
    <place>NZ</place>
    <price>0</price>
    <ordernumber>12345</ordernumber>
    <objectid>1</objectid>
    </Orderitem>
  <Orderitem>
    <name>Desktop2</name>
    <place>NZ</place>
    <price>0</price>
    <ordernumber>12345</ordernumber>
   </Orderitem>
</listoforders>
```

Output:

```
   <listoforders>
     <Orderitem>
    <name>Desktop</name>
    <place>NZ</place>
    <netprice>120</netprice>
   <quantity>2</quantity>
   <itemproperties>
   <name>phoneid</name>
   <value>1234</value>
   </itemproperties>
   </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop2</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <netprice>140</price>
        <ordernumber>1234</ordernumber>
    </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop2</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <netprice>60</price>
       <ordernumber>1234</ordernumber>           
       <objectid>1</objectid>

    </Orderitem>
     <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop2</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <netprice>60</price>
    <ordernumber>1234</ordernumber>        
    </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop2</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
    <ordernumber>12345</ordernumber>            
    <netprice>130</price>
    </Orderitem>
            <Orderitem>
    <name>Desktop</name>
    <place>NZ</place>
    <netprice>120</netprice>
    <quantity>3</quantity>
    <associationid>2</associationid>
    <itemproperties>
        <name>phoneid</name>
        <value>12345</value>
    </itemproperties>
   </Orderitem>
   <Orderitem>
    <name>Desktop2</name>
    <place>NZ</place>
    <netprice>40</netprice>
    <ordernumber>12345</ordernumber>
   </Orderitem>
   <Orderitem>
    <name>Desktop2</name>
    <place>NZ</place>
    <netprice>40</netprice>
    <ordernumber>12345</ordernumber>
    <objectid>1</objectid>

   </Orderitem>
  <Orderitem>
    <name>Desktop2</name>
    <place>NZ</place>
    <price>40</price>
    <ordernumber>12345</ordernumber>
   </Orderitem>
    </listoforders>
```

I used a key, a variable to match and div rule, but i am unable to pass to variables across templates.

XSLT: Sample xslt

```
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"  
indent="yes"/>
            <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
   <xsl:key name="partnumber" 
 match="Orderitem[name='Desktop']/itemproperties[name='phoneid'])" 
use="value" />
<xsl:template match="Orderitem[name='Desktop2]">

            <NetPrice>
            <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
            </NetPrice>

<xsl:variable select="quant" match="Orderitem[name='Desktop']/quantity" />

<xsl:variable name="amt" match="Orderitem[name='Desktop']/price" />


            </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Orderitem[../name='Desktop2'][key('partnumber', 
 ../ordernumber)]/>
 <xsl:if test="price = 0"
 <Price>xsl:value-of select="$amot div $quant"</Price>
 </xsl:if>
 <xsl:if test="price != 0"
 <Price> xsl:value-of select="price" </Price>  
 </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the XSLT you are having trouble with? Thank you.

Comment: Done, not sure if it is helpful, please see my approach. There is with-param i could have used for carrying values from one template to another? Will see for possible approaches from our fellow members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the updated sample input XML, the solution has been modified to cater to multiple occurrences of *Desktop* value in the XML.

The solution does not use `<xsl:key>` but uses a similar filter criteria for looping and calculating the `<netprice>` required in the output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- match elements Desktop2 and Desktop3 -->
    <xsl:template match="Orderitem[name='Desktop2'] | Orderitem[name='Desktop3']">
        <xsl:copy>  
            <!-- copy all elements except price -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::price)]" />
            <!-- logic for calculating netprice -->
            <xsl:call-template name="calcNetPrice">
                <xsl:with-param name="price" select="price" />
                <xsl:with-param name="orderNum" select="ordernumber" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- calculate net price -->
    <xsl:template name="calcNetPrice">
        <xsl:param name="price" />
        <xsl:param name="orderNum" />
        <xsl:variable name="matchingSet" select="//Orderitem[name='Desktop']/itemproperties[name='phoneid'][value=$orderNum]" />
        <netprice>
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- check whether a match is found -->
                <xsl:when test="$matchingSet != ''">
                    <!-- loop only for matching set -->
                    <xsl:for-each select="$matchingSet">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="$price = 0">
                                <xsl:value-of select="../price div ../quantity" />
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$price" />
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
                <!-- else set the netprice to the input price -->
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$price" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </netprice>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<listoforders>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <price>120</price>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
        <associationid>2</associationid>
        <itemproperties>
            <name>phoneid</name>
            <value>1234</value>
        </itemproperties>
    </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop2</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <ordernumber>1234</ordernumber>
        <netprice>120</netprice>
    </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop2</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <ordernumber>1234</ordernumber>
        <objectid>1</objectid>
        <netprice>60</netprice>
    </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop2</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <ordernumber>1234</ordernumber>
        <netprice>60</netprice>
    </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop3</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <ordernumber>1234</ordernumber>
        <netprice>130</netprice>
    </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <price>120</price>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
        <associationid>2</associationid>
        <itemproperties>
            <name>phoneid</name>
            <value>123456</value>
        </itemproperties>
    </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop2</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <ordernumber>123456</ordernumber>
        <netprice>40</netprice>
    </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop2</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <ordernumber>123456</ordernumber>
        <objectid>1</objectid>
        <netprice>40</netprice>
    </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop2</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <ordernumber>123456</ordernumber>
        <netprice>40</netprice>
    </Orderitem>
    <Orderitem>
        <name>Desktop2</name>
        <place>NZ</place>
        <ordernumber>123456</ordernumber>
        <netprice>130</netprice>
    </Orderitem>
</listoforders>
```

**EDIT:** Solution modified to handle *Desktop2*, *Desktop3* values having `ordernumber` not matching to any of the *Desktop* `itemproperties[name='phoneid']/value`.

Comment: My first *desktop* can be anywhere, not necessarily the first node, so there will be a problem in declaring variables in that case isnt it, since i cant define the xpath?

Comment: Are you saying that the XPath for the value `Desktop` will be different everytime and not as per the sample input XML? Can you show an example?

Comment: I have modified the answer. As long as the following structure `Orderitem[name='Desktop']` and it's child nodes comply with the shared structure, the location of the `name = desktop` should not be a problem. However if there is a change in the nesting of the remaining child nodes i.e. `itemproperties`, `price`, `quantity`, then there could be a problem with the XPath. If you can share all the possibilities then a generic solution can be worked out.

Comment: it can be anywhere, jumbled order of same example, currently its *desktop*,*desktop2*,*desktop2*,*desktop3*, it can be *desktop2*,*desktop2*,*desktop*, *desktop*, with different *phoneid*, *desktop2*,*desktop*,*desktop3 etc*, multiple *desktop*, and multiple *desktop2*,*desktop3*,

Comment: the problem with // is , it looks for entire xml and if the xml is big, then there can be a problem isnt it , so i tried in template and stored in a variable via template, is there a way to use variable declared in a template in another template.! Thanks

Comment: If there are multiple _desktop_, then it is altogether a different input XML and will have a completely new solution. The above solution was shared based on the input XML posted in the question. You will have to update the sample input XML based on all the scenarios and conditions in order to get a comprehensive solution.

Comment: Thanks , updated the xmls and added a point tha the initial structure can be repeated 'n' number of times, in different order and not just 1 occurrence.

Comment: Thanks. For certain _Desktop2_, there are multiple `<price>` nodes having value either `0` or `non-zero`. Which one is to be considered?

Comment: This piece of code"../price div ../quantity" /> quantity is not passed in the template , isnt it.?

Comment: It is not required to be passed. That is the `price` and `quantity` of the current _Desktop_ which will act as the `<netprice>` for _Desktop2_ and _Desktop3_ wherever they have `price = 0`. `../` indicates going up a level from the current node.

Comment: This does not work for 'Desktop2' or 'Desktop3' which doesnot match any phoneid/ordernumber, isnt it. Sorry if that rule is not explicitly stated here.Price becomes null there.

Comment: You can use this XSLT to further tweak as per your newer requirements or add your new requirement in the sample input.

Comment: I have updated the answer to handle this new requirement. If there are more requirements, you need to open new question.